# yii does not translate korean language

Tags: yii, localization

In database, I set language code of Korean - 'ko', but when yii print errors, these errors is english default like this: 
`이메일 cannot be blank.`.
 
Semilar with Maori...
So, what exactly language code of these languages? 
And where I can see list of language codes which supported by Yii?
Thanks...

Comment: Check /framework/message/ko directory, if not exist check your version. Download latest version with korean language support

Comment: as rightly pointed out by Sergey, in yii 1.1.11 i think its `ko_kr`